# Remote svn HEAD revision is lower than my local HEAD revision

Tags: svn, version-control

Something happened to my remote SVN server and the last revision now is lower than my local revision, something like remote HEAD=160, local HEAD=266.

I'm having trouble committing my higher version to the remote SVN, the error it displays is :

```
svn: E200014: Commit failed (details follow):    
svn: E200014: Base checksum mismatch on '/trunk/.../detail.tt':
       expected:  3a404f9d1e0bfea1f408dabaa9186dfc
         actual:  90ca3254bb5fe9103f00ab289a5a5390
```

What I should do to commit my last version to the server? I have working copies of this project in production, and I think if I do a "svn update" now the project will break.

Thanks!

Comment: Basically: do a checkout of the last revision you have somewhere. Copy the laster version of your working copy somewhere, and remove the .svn directories (`find -name '.svn' -delete`), then recursively copy the working copy over your latest svn checkout, commit in one huge commit. Then .svn is OK, your working copies aren't, but should be the same as svn, so make a new checkout for those.

Comment: And of course: svn is not a backup tool: backup svn repositories in multiple locations. Take the same care with (incremental) backups you'd usually use for databases.